# Heroku app works great on few computers but not the others. Could running "heroku restart" cause the issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

I am running into a very odd issue and coming up short with identifying the issue. I don't even know if it is a front-end, server or Heroku issue.

I am managing a Rails App (with React front-end), hosting on Heroku. It is a workforce management and dispatching app. It has been working fine the whole time, until earlier today, when I made a huge feature deployment. The deployment was successful, and I tested the old & new features fine on all of our testing computers. After deployment, I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` and `heroku restart`. During this time, we have customers using the web app on their local computers, in different time zones.

Few minutes later, I got a call from multiple customers, each mentioning that at least one of their dispatching features is not working, all of which were older features/components that shouldn't have been affected. Some say they cant see their workers. One say they cant see jobs on a particular day. Some say they cant see jobs on another. When I check the `heroku logs`, I see no errors whatsoever. Routes are called fine and things are passed correctly back to the front-end. When logging into their app with master credentials, we also were unable to replicate ANY of these issues on ANY of our computers. All of our customers uses Chrome, but checking on both Mac and Windows reveal no issues from our ends. Yet, the issue still remains.

We then decided to revert our deployment and deployed an earlier version. Same thing. Everything works on ours, and customers continue to say these features/components just appear...blank. We tried `heroku run rake tmp:clear` to clear heroku cache, still no luck.

Comment: My first suspect would be caching. You'll need to check for model, action and fragment caches.

Comment: @fylooi Thank you for the response. We considered that as well, however, the components that are affected are child components of a parent React component, which itself is rendered on a view template, yielded to `application.html.erb`. Looking at the DOM, the compiled javascript looks something like this `application-[timestamp_or_unique_build_id].js`. Furthermore, if it is a cache issue, wouldn't all of the issues be about the same component? Thank you.

Comment: Fragment caching can use conditional keys (eg. `cache([current_user.id, current_user.updated_at])`). See whether `Rails.cache.clear` helps. I'd also look into anything using timestamps for versioning. Also check whether there's anything dependent on the user's session / cookies / local storage.